# Postman: Could not get any response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, postman

My Django Rest API views.py:

```
# encoding: utf-8
from fileupload.response import JSONResponse, response_mimetype
from fileupload.models import *
from rest_framework.views import *
from rest_framework.parsers import *
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

"""A simple API for file upload."""
class FileUploadView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = ()
    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(FileUploadView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def put(self, request):
        print "xxx:", request
        try:
            psfile = MyFile.objects.create(file=request.FILES['file'])
            psfile.save()
            data = {'files': 'testing'}
            response = Response(data)
        except Exception as e:
            print "Exception when put file:", e
            data = { 'error' : str(e)}
            response = Response(data)

        return response
```

setting.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ()
}
```

I am doing PUT in Postman with Postman Interceptor enabled. 
Tried to put the file in the body as form-data.
But failed with the following error:

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to https://ip/projectname/api/upload/.
Why this might have happened:

 1. The server couldn't send a response:
        Ensure that the backend is working properly
 2. SSL connections are being blocked:
        Fix this by importing SSL certificates in Chrome
 3. Cookies not being sent: Use the Postman Interceptor extension
 4. Request timeout:
        Change request timeout in Settings > General
```

**Any ideas? Thanks in advance.**

**UPDATE**

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/506

http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/28/using-self-signed-certificates-with-postman/